# Cannot import matplotlib into Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, raspberry-pi2

I am attempting to teach myself programming and keep running into problems downloading modules I need for basic tutorials.

My latest attempt has been to get the `matplotlib` module into my Python 3 environment.  I have tried so many different install packages and so many advice I found on the internet that I cannot remember how I originally got the module.  But it seemed that everything went well with the installation process.

I am using a Raspberry Pi2 throughout all of this with the Raspbian OS installed.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Mar  1 2013, 11:53:50)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

Comment: How did you installed `matplotlib`?

Comment: Maybe you have installed matplotlib for python2.

Comment: "But it seemed that everything went well with the installation process"--> If you're getting an error, then no, it didn't go well. Try reinstalling and write here how you're installing.

Comment: where is it I can paste a copy of my terminal window now so that I can show you?  What I am attempting to paste goes over the character limit.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible that you actually installed the library for python 2. I would use pip to install the modules that you need. If you don't already have it installed, run this first command in the shell:

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

This program can be called with "pip3" or maybe "pip-3.2" in the shell.

To install mathplotlib with it, try running:

> pip3 install matplotlib

or

> pip-3.2 install matplotlib

That should install the Python 3 module for you.

Comment: the pip-3.2 install was going through the motions and then I received a message- (Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages))
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    The required version of distribute (>=0.6.28) is not available,



install a more recent version first, using

'easy_install -U distribute'.



(Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages))

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 2 in /home/pi/build/matplotlib

Comment: i attempted to copy paste the complete text on my terminal  into this box, but was over characters.  Should I put this into the "Answer Your Question Box"?

Comment: Try running the 'easy_install -U distribute' command and see if that fixes it. Run it as root with sudo or while logged in as root.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by rpi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo easy_install -U distribute
sudo: easy_install: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo easy_install -U distribute
sudo: easy_install: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo 'easy_install -U distribute'
sudo: easy_install -U distribute: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo easy_install-U distribute
sudo: easy_install-U: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo easy_install-U distribute
sudo: easy_install-U: command not found
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo easy_install -u distribute
sudo: easy_install: command not found

Comment: im not sure what you mean by run it as root.  I'm guessing im in the root directory due to the ~ being in the prompt line?

Comment: Running the command with sudo in front of it should have sufficed. It seems that you do not have the python setup tools installed. Try this: "sudo apt-get install python-setuptools". Then try that easy_install command again.